# Nice coloring a $10\times 10$ square

Tags: combinatorics, coloring

We call a coloring of a square with black and white colors nice if none of black square share same segments.Prove that the nice coloring cases of a $10\times 10$ square is more than $10^{15}$ and less than $10^{25}$.

It is to hard to handle with calculating it because we should divide every case to $2$ case if the $1\times 1$ square is black or white then how can we make the prove?I have tried using induction but it doesn't work for $1\times 1$ case so I didn't go anymore.Any hints?

Comment: "if non of black square doesn't have same segments." Did not get this line. What is a segment ?

Comment: @A---B Sth that connects two vertexes.

Comment: @TahaAkbari Still don't get your problem. You mean you have a $10 \times 10$ checkboard (with nonstandard coloring) so coloured, that no two black squares are next to each other, i.e. share a side?

Comment: @ctst Yes then we want to know how many boareds are like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The total number of ways to color each $2\times2$ square is $1+4+2=7$. So the total number of nice coloring is less than $7^{25}$. So that settles the upper inequality.

For the lower inequality consider the chessboard and consider all of the $2^{50}$ colorings that result from repainting some of the black squares white. We have $2^{50}>10^{15}$ so we are done.

Comment: if you want to prove $2^{50}>10^{15}$ you can notice $2^{10}> 10^3$ and so $2^{50}>10^{15}$